# context of file inclusion in php

Tags: php, function, file-inclusion

Good morning,

I am trying to to learn how the file inclusion in php works. Today, I am having a problem that I can not solve. This is my scenario:

**Files at same directory:**

```
- config.php
- db.php
- functions.php
- form.php
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$config['json_file'] = 'test.json';
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function writeInFile()
{
    echo $config['json_file']; // just for debugging porpuses
    file_put_contents($config['json_file'], json_encode(time()));
}
```

**model.php**

```
<?php
class Model{

    public function __construct();

    function create()
    {
        writeInFile();
    }
}
```

**form.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('functions.php');
include('model.php');

$model = new \Model();
$m->create();
```

When I execute the `form.php` I get this error:

> Warning: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Filename
>   cannot be empty in
>   functions.php

I know that this happens because the var `$config['json_file']` is null inside of `writeInFile()` in functions.php. But, theorically it should works because I am doing the inclusion at the begginig of form.php. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you need to pass a parameter to `writeInFile()`

Comment: I do not think so.  It is because file_put_contents need a filename to write,  it because the config var arrives as null at this function

Comment: @manix - You can either pass `$config` into the function as a parameter; or you can declare it as a global variable. Otherwise, it's out of scope. That's why you're seeing the null value - `$config` is out of scope.

Comment: In this case,  what is the scope of config.php?

Comment: @manix - when you include a file, it's effectively the same as cutting and pasting the contents of the included file. So any variables you've defined in config.php will have the same scope as `$model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read variable scope from here [variable scope][1]

[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php .

Right at the begining it sais that a function from another file that was included can't use a variable from another file beause it is considered to be in local scope . That's why you get error . Read more about var scope .